# Focus on Window After Three Finger Swipe to a Full Screen App in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox

I have an app in full screen mode in Mac OSX (click on the green circle).  I can three finger swipe to my desktop or back to the application.  However, the issue is if I'm in my desktop and three finger swipe to the full screen app I have to 'click' somewhere to focus the app.  Otherwise, if I just start typing it types in the window I was in on my previous desktop.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Use case:

Install VirtualBox and install another OS.  Launch the OS in full screen mode.  Be in previous desktop and launch TextEdit with a new document.  Three finger swipe to the full screen OS and begin typing.  The text will show up in TextEdit instead of focusing on the OS instance.

Comment: I cannot replicate this with Chrome in fullscreen mode. Have you tried Command-TAB to the fullscreen app? This may be a limitation of the hypervisor.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I added this option to the plist.info of VirtualBox to prevent the Mac OSX menu from appearing when moving the mouse cursor to the top of the screen.  <key>LSUIElement</key> <string>1</string>  This prevents the virtualized instance from appearing on the OSX app drawer and I cannot Command-Tab to it.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Looks like that is the problem.  If I remove that key from the plist.info file the behavior is normal when I three finger swipe to the application.  Thanks for your help.